# Arduino 400 bad request with ESP8266

Tags: html, arduino, http-get, esp8266

I am trying to make a GET request using Arduino and ESP8266.

I am using this code:

```
AT+CIPSEND=140
GET taub-prayer-ramym/girls HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io\r\nUser-Agent: ESP8266_HTTP_Client\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
```

But I'm getting this as a return:

```
+IPD,187:HTTP/1.0 400 Bad request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

<html><body><h1>400 Bad request</h1>
Your browser sent an invalid request.
</body></html>
CLOSED
```

I have tried to fix the syntax but have not succeeded. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to dump the query using tcpdump ou wireshark, to see what's wrong.
I have sent the query and I got a `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: @Ôrel did you find a solution?

Comment: No, can you do a working request on a browser or using curl ? I get `No Cloud9 workspace is bound to this domain name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I HAVE SUCCEDED.. CHANGE URL TO:

https://taub-prayer-ramym.c9.io/girls

Comment: Hi how did you fix it?